# PHP MVC: where to instantiate an object of user authentication?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, pdo

Where should I instantiate an object of user authentication?

Should I instantiate it in a parent class then its children can access the authenticated from it like this below?

```
class Core
{
    /**
     * Properties that to be shared by extended classed inherited from it.
     */ 
    protected $connection;
    protected $authentication;

    /**
     * Each extended classed inherited from this class require the db connection.
     */
    public function __construct($connection) 
    {
        // Construct the connection.
        $this->connection = $connection;

        // Construct the authencated user data.
        $this->authentication = new Authentication($this->connection,AUTHENTICATED_USER_SIGNATURE);
    }
}

Class Controller extends Core
{
  // authenticated data needed here.
}
```

or should I instantiate it **outside** the `Core` and pass it in its children like this below?

```
Class Controller extends Core
{
    public function __construct($connection, $authentication) 
    {
        // Construct the connection.
        $this->connection = $connection;

        // Construct the authencated user data.
        $this->authentication = $authentication;
    }
}
```

I prefer the option one. But which one is the common practice?

Comment: Both are common practice...more like a big-endian/little-endian question :) Any reason for your preference of option one?

Comment: I prefer and use option 2 but both are good, do what you feel better working with.

Comment: Having a `Core` class that everything extends from is only going to lead to problems. Also never instantiate objects in the constructor. If an object has a dependency inject it into the constructor. Doing authentication in controllers often leads to code duplication. A common place is to do it after the request has been routed.

Comment: `Also never instantiate objects in the constructor.` - can I ask why is it bad to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @tealou If you instantiate objects in the constructor then that object is tied to those specific instances, they are tightly coupled which is the opposite of what you want to achieve when developing software. Also when instantiating the object the constructors signature lies and says it has no dependencies when really it does, it just instantiates them in the constructor method. There are piles of more reasons, Google tight coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your code to be flexible and testable you should go for the latter. The first will introduce a hard dependency on `Authentication` which might be different based on other authentication requirements. Therefor `Authentication` should be an interface so you are free to throw in other implementations if the needs rises.